# Why doesn't Ruby have an is_an? method?

Tags: ruby

Why doesn't Ruby have an `is_an?` method? For example:

```
[].is_an? Array?
```

Comment: Check [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F).

Comment: It's ironical that you are looking for `an` rather than the existing `a` while you typed `a` in place where you should have `an`.

Comment: Sometimes little utilities like these wind up in the Ruby on Rails ActiveSupport library. Someone attempted to add it, but it was not pulled in by the maintainers: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6243.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is `kind_of?`

See here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F

Answer (score 7):

You might consider using [`is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) instead eg.:

```
if [].is_a? Array
   puts "Array"
end
```

If you really need to have `is_an?` you might also achieve it with an alias:

```
class Object
  alias :is_an? :is_a?
end

if [].is_an? Array
   puts "Array"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails maintainer Andrew White [gave](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6243#issuecomment-5647014) the following reason:

> it's purely an English language idiosyncrasy and since many (most?)
>   Ruby programmers do not have English as their primary language they
>   may not be aware of it, leading to confusion.

See this pull request for the full discussion on the topic:
[Improved readability for object introspection (is_a?)](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6243)

Maybe it would get added if someone opened the same pull request in the Ruby repository!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has `is_a?` already which does what you want.  You could make `is_an?` in 3 lines of code if you want but I think it's a bad idea.  There are too many synonyms already in the standard Ruby library that make it harder than necessary to learn.  I just recently learned that Enumerable's map and collect are the same.

Comment: I personally think this would do no harm. It helps write more readable code.

Comment: you can alias in one line if you like.

Answer (score 2):

#### Create an `is_an?` alias initializer.

We ended up creating a little initializer to add this alias into our project, since we are mostly English speakers and prefer the grammatical correctness that `is_an?` affords:

**`config/initializers/is_an.rb`**

```
# Aliases `is_an?` to `is_a?` so we correctly use `is_an?( Array )` instead of `is_a?( Array )`
#
# Surprisingly, not in the Ruby core, but it almost made it into the Rails core.
# For the discussion, see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6243
#
class Object
  alias is_an? is_a?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F